# Testing if something is a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey all, I am trying to test if the argument passed into my function is a class name so that I may compare it to other classes using instanceof.

For example:

```
function foo(class1, class2) {
  // Test to see if the parameter is a class.
  if(class1 is a class)
  {
    //do some kind of class comparison.
    if(class2 is a class)
    {
       if(class1 instanceof class2)
       {
          //...
       }
    }
    else
    {
       //...
    }
  }
  else
    //...
}
```

Is this possible? I am having trouble googleing an answer.

Comment: Are you using a library that implements classical inheritance in JavaScript?

Comment: No, I'm just using plain old javascript :d

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is really no such thing as a "class" in javascript -- everything but primitives are an object. Even functions are objects.

instanceof DOES work with functions though. Check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator).

```
function Car(make, model, year)
{
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
var mycar = new Car("Honda", "Accord", 1998);
var a = mycar instanceof Car;    // returns true
var b = mycar instanceof Object; // returns true
```

Comment: "everything is an object" - Not exactly. The Primitive types(number, string, bool, null and undefined) are not objects.

Comment: @AndreasGrech - not exactly, even primitive types has properties and methods and prototype chain, etc... so they are also some kind of object

Comment: Note that this changed with ES2015, which added classes to JS.

Answer (score 30):

**Now that we have native implementations of ES6**, there are "real classes". These are largely syntactic sugar for prototypal inheritance as with constructor functions, but there are subtle differences and the two are not completely interchangeable.

So far, the only way I've found is to get the `.toString()` of the object's prototype's constructor function and check if it starts with `class` OR if the object has a constructor and the `.toString()` of *that* starts with `class`.

Note that if your code is compiled (ie: most Babel or TypeScript setups), then this will return `function...` instead of `class...` at runtime (since classes are transpiled to constructor functions).

```
function isClass(obj) {
  const isCtorClass = obj.constructor
      && obj.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'
  if(obj.prototype === undefined) {
    return isCtorClass
  }
  const isPrototypeCtorClass = obj.prototype.constructor 
    && obj.prototype.constructor.toString
    && obj.prototype.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'
  return isCtorClass || isPrototypeCtorClass
}
```

This will only work in native environments (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, node.js, etc.) that have implemented `class` for code that has not been transpiled to `function`.

Usage:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
isClass(A) // true
isClass(new A()) // true
isClass(B) // true
isClass(new B()) // true

function C() {}
isClass(C) // false
isClass(new C()) // false
isClass({}) // false
isClass(Date) // false
isClass(new Date()) // false

//These cases return 'true' but I'm not sure it's desired
isClass(Object.create(A)) // true    
const x = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(x, A)
isClass(x) // true
```

If there is a better way, I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: In my opinion, isClass(new A()) should return false. A is a class, but new A() is an instance of a class, not a class.

Comment: I would add at beginning: `if (obj === undefined || obj === null){return false}`

Answer (score 21):

Here's a quick and dirty way to determine if you have a class or a function.

```js
function myFunc() {};
class MyClass {};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myFunc);
// -> [ 'length', 'name', 'arguments', 'caller', 'prototype' ]

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass);
// -> [ 'length', 'prototype', 'name' ]
```

So we know we have a function and *not* a class if `arguments` is a property name:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myFunc).includes('arguments');
// -> true

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass).includes('arguments');
// -> false
```

Arrow functions and `aysnc` functions won't have an `arguments` property name or a `prototype`. A more complete example might look like this (assuming we know the input can only be a function or a class):

```
function isFunction(funcOrClass) {
  const propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(funcOrClass);
  return (!propertyNames.includes('prototype') || propertyNames.includes('arguments'));
}
```

```js
function isFunction(funcOrClass) {
  const propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(funcOrClass);
  return (!propertyNames.includes('prototype') || propertyNames.includes('arguments'));
}

console.log('class isFunction?', isFunction(class A {}));
console.log('function isFunction?', isFunction(function() {}));
console.log('async function isFunction?', isFunction(async function() {}));
console.log('arrow function isFunction?', isFunction(() => {}));
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: But is it certain that "arguments" is there as an own-property always? It would seem to me it is there only if the function is being called. Whereas if you pass the function as an argument and try to inspect the properties of such an argument it would not be there.

Comment: @PanuLogic I'm not sure what you mean. This works for me:

`function myFunc() {};
function checkProps(func) { console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(func)); }
checkProps(myFunc)`

Comment: In at least node.js environment:  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(() => 123).includes('arguments');   //  === false

Comment: @PanuLogic You're using an arrow function which also doesn't have `prototype`, so if you know you're getting either a class or a function, you can check for `prototype` as well. I'll update my answer. Note that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(function () { 123 }).includes('arguments');` works in Node, as expected.

Comment: Good to know. I still wonder a bit if it's part of the standard that 'arguments' is always accessible as own property for all functions except arrow-functions. For instance MDN says: " ... Arguments is an Array-like object accessible INSIDE functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function." It seems to me they are meant to be used inside a function call so whether they can always be accessed from outside of a function as well according to the standard(s) I don't know.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't aware that a class function didn't come with all the standard function properties

Comment: Unfortunately it may not work if the function was declared on script where `"use strict"` was being set.

Answer (score 2):

I know that using `constructor.name` on a function will return "Function" but doing so on an ES6 class instance will return the name of the class.

I do use it like this:

```
function isAClassInstance(item){
 return item.constructor.name !== "Function" && item.constructor.name !== "Object";
}

class A {};
function B(){};
const aInstanceClass = new A();
const bFunctionInstance = new B();
const bFunction = B;
const aClass = A;
console.log(aInstanceClass.constructor.name); /*Will return "A"*/
console.log(bFunctionInstance.constructor.name); /*Will return "B"*/
console.log(A.constructor.name); /*Will return "Function"*/
console.log(B.constructor.name); /*Will return "Function"*/
console.log(bFunction.constructor.name); /*Will return "Function"*/
console.log("is A a class instance: ", isAClassInstance(aClass)); /*false*/
console.log("is B a class instance: ", isAClassInstance(aClass)); /*false*/
console.log("is aInstanceClass a class: ", isAClassInstance(aInstanceClass)); /*true*/
console.log("is bFunction a class: ", isAClassInstance(bFunction)); /*false*/
console.log("is bFunctionInstance a class: ", isAClassInstance(bFunctionInstance)); /*true*/
```

For the cases i used this worked perfectly.

note: since a class is technically a function doing `new A()` and `new B()` are both the same thus returning the same result from isAClassInstance.
The only way to dinstinguish a function from a class is to not use `new` on a function and keep this keyword for class only.

Hope this will help :).

Comment: `new A()` is not a class; `A` is the class and `new A()` is an instance of that class. Is there a way to have isClass distinguish A and B, like this?  `isClass(A) === true` but `isClass(B) === false` ?

Comment: I actually haven't thought about it, unfortunatly from my understanding it is not possible to distinguish a function from a class since they are both (under the hood) basically the same, class are only syntax sugar but in the end new A() is the same as doing new B(), i rewrote the test to make it more explicit

Comment: Doesn't `(function() {}).constructor.name` throw an error in `'use strict'` mode?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is by checking if the function prototype has property other than `constructor` and checking if the function prototype is `Function.prototype`.
This solution can also work even after transpiled with babel, or the script is running with "use strict". But this solution will only work if the class have at least one public function, or have extend other class.

```js
function isClass(func){
  // Class constructor is also a function
  if(!(func && func.constructor === Function) || func.prototype === undefined)
    return false;
  
  // This is a class that extends other class
  if(Function.prototype !== Object.getPrototypeOf(func))
    return true;
  
  // Usually a function will only have 'constructor' in the prototype
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(func.prototype).length > 1;
}


// ----Example----

class Fruit{
  hello(){} // At least must have one public function
}

// Or at least it extend other class
class Pear extends Fruit{}

console.log(isClass(Fruit)); // true
console.log(isClass(Pear)); // true
console.log(isClass(function(){})); // false
console.log(isClass(function(){"use strict"})); // false
console.log(isClass(() => {})); // false
console.log(isClass({hello: 1})); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have classes. It has functions which, when used with `new`, can be used to produce object instances. Therefore, you really want to test if `class2` is a function. There are numerous ways of accomplishing this; the current (1.3) implementation of isFunction() in jQuery looks like this:

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
    return toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
},
```

...But see here for a rundown of the different methods:
[Best method of testing for a function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405164/best-method-of-testing-for-a-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Note that this changed with ES2015, and modern JS _does_ have classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
function isClass(C) { 
    return typeof C === "function" && C.prototype !== undefined;
}
```

Every class is internally just a **function** that creates instances of this class, plus a `prototype` property that's assigned to `[[Prototype]]` of newly created objects to make them behave like instances of this particular class. So, to check if `C` is a class, you need to check these two things - this is what the `isClass()` code above does.

Note that all functions declared with `function` keyword can also be used with `new` as constructors, and inside `instanceof` tests. They're equivalent to classes, and have a `prototype` likewise, so every function of this type is (correctly) recognized as a class by the `isClass()` function above.

```js
console.log(isClass(Object));    // true
console.log(isClass(Number));    // true
console.log(isClass({a:1}));     // false
console.log(isClass(123));       // false
console.log(isClass("123"));     // false

class A {}
class B extends A {}

console.log(isClass(A));         // true
console.log(isClass(B));         // true
console.log(isClass(new B()));   // false

function f(name) { this.name = name; }

console.log(isClass(f));         // true
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround if you want to test only classes that you created yourself: adding a specific static property to all your class definition.

Indeed the test only work on testing your own classes. You can override javascript built-in objects (the list for ECMA-262 can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) but it is obviously not recommended.

```js
class MyClass {
  static isClass = true;

  constructor() {
  }
}


function myFunction () {
}


const var1 = MyClass;
const var2 = myFunction;
const var3 = Array;

console.log("var1 is a class: " + (var1.isClass ? "true" : "false"));
console.log("var2 is a class: " + (var2.isClass ? "true" : "false"));
console.log("var3 is a class: " + (var3.isClass ? "true" : "false"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey just updating an old thread I took one of the above answers and made it work with all the predefined classes in javascript. eg. String, Map, extra

Original:

```js
function isClass(obj) {
  const isCtorClass = obj.constructor
      && obj.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'
  if(obj.prototype === undefined) {
    return isCtorClass
  }
  const isPrototypeCtorClass = obj.prototype.constructor 
    && obj.prototype.constructor.toString
    && obj.prototype.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'
  return isCtorClass || isPrototypeCtorClass
}
```

New:

```js
export const isClass = (obj) => {
    if (obj == null || typeof obj == "undefined") { return false; }
    const isCtorClass = obj.constructor
        && obj.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'
    const isNativeCtorClass= obj.constructor && 
                                  obj.constructor.name != "Function" && 
                                  obj.constructor.name in global;
    if (obj.prototype === undefined) {
        return isCtorClass || isNativeCtorClass
    }
    const isPrototypeCtorClass = obj.prototype.constructor
        && obj.prototype.constructor.toString
        && obj.prototype.constructor.toString().substring(0, 5) === 'class'

    const isNativePrototypeCtorClass = obj.prototype.constructor.name in global && (
            global[obj.prototype.constructor.name] == obj.constructor || 
            global[obj.prototype.constructor.name] == obj
        );
    return isCtorClass || isPrototypeCtorClass || isNativeCtorClass || isNativePrototypeCtorClass
}
```

This checks the object in the global javascript object to check if it's a currently registered object.

Let me know if this would break for some use cases but it works for me.

```js
isClass(function test() {})    // false
isClass(() => {})              // false
isClass(function  String() {}) // false
isClass(String)                // true
isClass("")                    // true
isClass(0)                     // true
isClass(class Test {})         // true
isClass(new Number(0))         // true
isClass(new (class Test{})())  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the answers here I built out my own internal solution. I wanted to ensure that it only returns true if its a Class and not an instance of a class and I wanted distinguish between ES6 and classic / builtin (eg. Array) classes.

This solution should work for anything you throw at it. Please let me know if you find any exceptions.

```js
// Will only return true for ES6 Class definitions
function isES6Class(o) {
    return isClass(o, {es6: true})
}

// Will return any class unless {es6:true} is passed (see isES6Class)
function isClass(o, opts) {
    if(!o)return false
    if(!o.prototype) return false
    if(__cls(o.constructor) || __cls(o.prototype.constructor)) return true
    if(opts && opts.es6) return false

    // Old school or builtin class
    // If is function that has name with first letter capitalized
    if((typeof o) === 'function'){ 
        var s = funcName(o)
        if (s.length > 0){
            var i = s.charCodeAt(0)
            if (i > 64 && i < 91){ return true }
        }
    }
    return false
    function __cls(v){
        return v.toString && v.toString().indexOf('class')===0
    }
}
// helper
var RE_FUNC_DEF = new RegExp("^\\s*function\\s*(\\S*)\\s*\\((.*)\\)");
function funcName(f){
    if (!f) return("(funcName() - f is Nothing!)")
    if(!_.isFunction(f))return("(funcName() - f is not a function!) - f = " + String(f))
    var s = f.toString(), m = s.match(RE_FUNC_DEF)
    if (m && m.length > 1) return m[1]
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nate answer, which is `isFunction` I refactored function to return `isClass` as my reserch and this question is how to check if something is a class.

```
function isClass(funcOrClass) {
    const propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(funcOrClass);
    return propertyNames.includes('prototype') && !propertyNames.includes('arguments');
}

function isFunction(funcOrClass) {
    return typeof funcOrClass === 'function' && !isClass(funcOrClass);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I haven't found any 100% certain way to figure out
if something is a class and not a function. The
accepted answer above works in most cases but if
someone redefines the method toString() of their
class it may break in that case. Why would they 
ever redefine toString()? I don't know, ask them
if they are still around :-)

So instead I took the approach of defining this
function:

```
function isClass(v)
{ if (typeof v !== "function")
  { return false;
  }
  if ( typeof v.isClass === "function" &&
       v.isClass()
     )
  { return true;
  }
}
```

This means I can mark my own classes as
being classes I recognize as classes by
giving them the static method isClass()
which returns true. If such classes have
subclasses the subclasses inherit the
method and are thus automatically recognized
as "classes" as well.

If I need to work with someone else's 
classes which does not have this method
I might first subclass their class so 
that my subclass is like their class 
except it also has the isClass() -method.

I hope the next version of EcmaScript will
remedy this lack of standardized solution
but for now this is the best I can do.

It has the additional benefit that I might 
in fact give the method isClass() to some
of my non-class-functions as well, which are 
not classes proper, and then be able to
treat such functions as if they were classes, 
for whatever reason I might want to.