# Typescript generic bound any object except any class

Tags: typescript, class, generics, typescript-generics, bounds

How to make a generic bound which excludes any class instances, but accepts any other object?

```js
class A {}
class B {
  name: string = '1'
}
interface C {
 name: string
}

// There should be a proper bound
function fn<T extends Record<string, any>>(v: T) {}

const a = new A()
const b = new B()
const c: C =  {name: '1'}

fn(a) // should be error
fn(b) // should be error
fn(c) // should be ok
```

After a lot of googling I think it's just not possible. But I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: TS’s structural type system does not distinguish class instance types from other object types, so this is not possible.  What is the use case?

Comment: Pretty much any recursive deep function that needs to modify objects but leaves classes as is.

Comment: Given that class instances are also objects, I'm not sure what you mean.  How would you implement that function in JavaScript?  Are you checking the `constructor` property or something?

Comment: These resources may be able to help you: [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and [Test if Class or Object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526559/testing-if-something-is-a-class-in-javascript)